# How to run Quarz Cron Job between specific time?

Tags: java, cron, quartz

I want to execute cron job between specific time. i.e. Cron job should execute every 15 minutes between 7:03 to 21:04?

I can manage between 7 to 9 but can't schedule between 7:03 to 9:05.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding your requirement clearly, AFAIK, you need two schedulers:

**First Scheduler (runs between hours 07:00 to 21:00):**

Cron expression should be like `0 3/15 7-20 * * *`

**0** - seconds

**3/15** - runs at 3rd, 18th, 33rd, 48th minutes of each hour

**7-20** - starting from 07AM to 08PM (included)

**Second Scheduler (runs ONLY at 21:04):**

Cron expression should be like `0 4 21 * * *` (which runs ONLY at **21:04**)

Comment: I need to execute every 15 minutes starting from 7:03 AM to 9:04 PM, this is not perform as like this

Comment: Yes I test it, See my question, It says job should start from 7:03 and end 9:04

Comment: Your job should end at 09AM? or 09PM?

Comment: 9:04 PM last execution, it should consider minute also

Comment: With the above expression, the last run will be at 09:03PM, but you want only at 09PM&4thminute i.e., there is an additional run at the 4th minute, am I right?

Comment: Yes, Correct, Also, Its last run would be on 8:47 PM not 9:03 PM

Answer (score 0):

Try with below cron expression

```
0 3/15 7-21 * * ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to run daily, you can try to use DailyTimeIntervalTrigger.
There you can set the start time (7:03) and end time (21:04) and choose the interval you want (in seconds, minutes, hours...)